# Detecting whether a background image is "too light" to display white text over

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation

I am building a mobile client app that gathers info about movies/TV shows from a website and displays it in a pretty format. When the user clicks on a show, they are taken to a page with the thumbnail for that show used as the background. This works well for most shows because they have dark thumbnails that contrast well with white text, however, some shows have a light background against which it's barely possible to distinguish white text. What's a programmatic way to determine whether or not the image is light, and adjust the color of the text accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple approach, which works for most real-world cases, and does not involve complex color-space conversions, or optical perception models:

- Calculate an average RGB value for the rectangular area of background where you are going to place the text. You can do this by simply calculating the average of each channel R, G, and B using the RGB values of the pixels in that area.
- Then pick "white" as the font color when R+B+G is smaller than (3*256)/2, and "black" otherwise (for 8 bit channels, of course).

I have used this a few times in the past, and it worked well for those cases.

Comment: _"Then pick "white" as the font color when R+B+G is smaller than (3*256)/2"_ Since you're calculating an average, wouldn't that be 256/2 or 128?

Comment: @Flater: I did not suggest to calculate a mixed average of all R, G, and B values , but one average for red, one for green and one for blue. So if (R,G,B) is the result of that calculation, R+G+B is in the range [0,3*255]. If one takes 3*356/2 or 3*255/2 as the cut point is pretty unimportant.

Comment: Gotcha, I misunderstood. I think it's mathematically equivalent anyway ;)

Comment: @Flater: indeed, now as you said it, it looks obvious ;-) I would still leave the description as it is, makes it easier to modify the approach in case one would give R, G and B values a different weight. AFAIK the "green" channel may be weighted higher than the other two, since it has a higher impact on the contrast.